# Exclude DataMembers from DataContract wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service Method returning region object containing list of countries and in country class i have also a region object can i remove this region object from WCF data contact

Comment: Simple: just don't put a `[DataMember]` attribute on that region property ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx) attribute?

> When applied to the member of a type, specifies that the member is not part of a data contract and is not serialized.